# How to store files on a router's NAND without writing the whole firmware

Tags: firmware, linux

I want to modify my ZyXEL P-2812HNU-F1 dsl router by storing some extra files in /etc. However, /etc is mounted as tmpfs so changes are lost on reboot. But there's probably a way around it ;)

```
# cat /proc/mounts 
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / yaffs2 ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /etc tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
[..snip..]
/dev/mtdblock4 /mnt/Config yaffs2 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/mtdblock3 /mnt/firmware yaffs2 rw,relatime 0 0

# touch /am-i-really-mounted-rw
touch: /am-i-really-mounted-rw: Read-only file system

# cat /proc/mtd 
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 01e00000 00020000 "rootfs,kernel1"
mtd1: 01e00000 00020000 "rootfs,kernel2"
mtd2: 00ac0000 00020000 "reserve"
mtd3: 02cc0000 00020000 "firmware"
mtd4: 00aa0000 00020000 "config"
mtd5: 00040000 00020000 "mrd_cert1"
mtd6: 00040000 00020000 "mrd_cert2"

# cat /proc/cmdline 
root=/dev/mtdblock0 rootfstype=yaffs2 console=ttyS0,115200 phym=128M mem=126M panic=1 vpe1_load_addr=0x87e00000M vpe1_mem=2M vpe1_wired_tlb_entries=0 

# uname -a
Linux router 2.6.32.42 #25 Mon Oct 5 14:41:26 CST 2015 mips unknown
```

So,

1. Why is / mounted rw but actually read-only?
2. Why are there two rootfs/kernel partitions? So the router can flash itself while running and then switch to the other upon boot?
3. Can I safely copy the running kernel/rootfs to the other mtdblock by using dd?
4. How do I boot from the other mtblock? I got a USB FTDI cable already.
5. Or, is there another way to write persistent files to /etc here?

Comment: Can you post contents of `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts`?

Comment: The reason I'm asking for it is that what `mount` usually does is just printing contents of `/etc/mtab` while the kernel has its own partition table stored in `/proc/mounts`. These days `/etc/mtab` is usually just a symlink to `/proc/mounts` but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so thanks to Arkadiusz' comment, I figured out that all I had to do was `mount /dev/root / -o remount,rw -t yaffs2` and presto, writable root!

Comment: Hmm, but this does not explain why `rootfs` has been mounted as read-write in the first place but writing fails as it's also `rw` in your `/proc/mounts`. Some filesystems such as `squashfs` are only read-only but `yaffs2` is not. Such situations when something is mounted as `rw` but writing fails also happens when using `NFS` or `CIFS` but it's not used in your case. Linux also automatically remounts disks to read-only when errors are found. Can you post output of `dmesg | grep -e mount -e roots -e read`?

Comment: Oh, wait, you have `/dev/root / yaffs2 ro,relatime 0 0`. Can you please paste *both* `/proc/mounts` and output of `mount`?